# Promise based node-postgres request under Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-postgres

I'm trying to implement a promise-based approach to accessing a PostgreSQL database. This is the original code:

```
// ./sql/config/pgQuery.js
module.exports = (text, values, cb) => {
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    client.query(text, values, (err, result) => {
      done();
      if (err) return cb(err);
      return cb(null, result.rows, result);
    });
  });
};

// ./routes/pg.js
router.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {
    const values = [];

    query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users', values, (err, rows, all) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users');
      res.status(204).end();
    });

    const text = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (date timestamptz)';
    query(text, values, (err, rows, all) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users');
      res.status(204).end();
    });
  });
```

This is what I come up with so far, but it doesn't work:

```
// ./sql/config/pgQuery.js
function promisePool() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return (text, values, cb) => {
      pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) { cb(err); return; }
        client.query(text, values, (err, result) => {
          done();
          if (err) { reject(err); return; }
          return resolve(cb(null, result.rows, result));
        });
      });
    };
  });
}
module.exports = promisePool;

// ./routes/pg.js
router.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {
    const values = [];
    query()
      .then('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users', values, (err, rows, all) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users');
        res.status(204).end();
      })
      .then('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (date timestamptz)', values, (err, rows, all) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users');
        res.status(204).end();
      });
  });
```

Thank You for your help!

Comment: For promise-based coding for PostgreSQL use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) instead.

Comment: If you write an answer I will accept it as the suggested library. I'm already using it.